# Is that right way to iterate LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, struts2, linkedhashmap

I am trying to iterate LinkedHashMap but its not coming in right i have attached the code below

```
for (int g = 0; g < list_Fields.size(); g++) {
    System.out.println("Hello ListOFFields:" + list_Fields.get(g));
    row = (LinkedHashMap) list_Fields.get(g);

    Iterator ie = row.keySet().iterator();
    while (ie.hasNext()) {
        String colName = ie.next().toString();
        System.out.println("<TD>" + colName + "</TD>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the output show up in your JSP page? Is that why there's HTML in there?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why it is made so clumsy.  Here is what we normally done when iterating collections in Java (as u r using LinkedHashMap, I assume you are using Java 5+)

```
// assume listField is Collection<Map<String,ANYTHING>> 
for (Map<String,ANYTHING> row : listFields) {
  for (String ie : row.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("<TD>" + ie +"</TD>");
  }
}
```

Comment: where as i am not using collection<Map<String,Anything>> I am using List<LinkedHashMap please how better i can do this

Comment: @Mohan, i think Adrian's code should work if list_fields is a collection/ List, have you tried it yet? btw, what exactly do you mean by "its not coming in right" ?

Comment: @MohanMaverick First, as aishwarya said, the code should work, please make sure you understand what the code means.  Second, it seems a bad smell to me that you are using the implementation class (LinkedHashMap) in variable declaration.  It just doesn't seems necessary to use List<LinkedHashMap<??,??> > instead of List<Map<??,??>>.  Anyway, even you use LinkedHashMap, my code still works...

Comment: ya i understood that and can u please tell me how iterate List<LikedHashmap> in struts2

Comment: @Mohan it has nothing to do with struts2, it is simply Java. And if you really understood, you should already know the answer.  What is the problem u r facing?...

Answer (score 3):

Modify it the way you want print statements
If you just want Keys then use keySet() instead of entrySet()

Here you go:

```
    public static  List<LinkedHashMap<Object,Object>> dummy = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<Object,Object>>();
public static void display(){
    for(LinkedHashMap<Object,Object> map : dummy){
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Object key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
                  //Your code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be like this:

```
for (Entry entry: map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over list of fields and inside of the iteration you iterate over collections of values. You will end-up with a table with row-per field with mixed amount of  in it.

If you want to get a simple table - change order of you fields/data collections and switch you iteration order that you iterate on rows first and on fields second:

```
List<Map<String,String>> rows = ...

for ( Map data : rows ) {
    System.out.println("<TR>");
    for ( String fld : list_Fields ) {
        System.out.println("<TD>" + data.get(fld) + "</TD>");
    }
    System.out.println("</TR>");
}
```